# 100vh not constant in Instagram browser (with bottom nav bar)

Tags: html, css, iphone, mobile

I have a problem.

I have a website that works with sections, that is to say we scroll and it changes section, they all have a height of 100vh.

Here is a very simple example of the site:
kylian.alwaysdata.net/other (on mobile only)

code HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" >
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="screen">
    <div class="content">
      lekjfosrejfiosfjh
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="screen2">
    <div class="content">
      lekjfosrejfiosfjh
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="screen">
    <div class="content">
      lekjfosrejfiosfjh
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code CSS :

```
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.screen {
  background-color: mediumpurple;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-height: -moz-available;
  min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
  min-height: fill-available;
}
.screen2 {
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-height: -moz-available;
  min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
  min-height: fill-available;
}
.content {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

So I use `-webkit-fill-available` which prevents the bar at the bottom on Instagram when it scrolls in and out from changing the size of my section, same on safari.
However this solution makes my section too small in height, when we scroll to the bottom we see clearly the next section that is to say that the sections are not big enough and do not make the whole height of the screen.

Screen of the problem:

[image]

If anyone knows how to do it, thank you :)

At the beginning I was using only `height: 100vh;` to define the size of my sections but on some mobile browsers with the navigation bar at the bottom that removes when you scroll it changed all my section sizes.

So I switched to `-webkit-fill-availabl`e but now as already said, my sections are too small in height :/

EDIT : Here is what it fiat if I put a size that adapts itself as "dvh" ( when there is content it is horrible we move a little and everything changes place :/ )
Link : https://www.youtube.com/shorts/U1xy5cBHs5M

Comment: Hey OP please try to use only relevant tags when asking, no JS here :) Also editor @Bumhan Yu - have a look at the tags when editing; I approved your edit in any case

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue solved by the `dvw` and `dvh` units; try `100dvh`.

> Unit dvh reflects the current viewport height. This unit excludes the user agent's interface, unlike unit vh, and updates as the current viewport height changes.
>
> Unit dvh reflects how much vertical viewport height the user agent's interface currently takes up. For instance, this will change as you scroll down a page on mobile, since the mobile URL bar moves out of your screen.
>
> https://terluinwebdesign.nl/en/css/incoming-20-new-css-viewport-units-svh-lvh-dvh-svw-lvw-dvw/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it's not really that.

-In fact the section takes the whole height of the phone but for example if the site is opened on Instagram (ios version anyway), we have a bar at the bottom and top of the screen that appears and removes when we scroll.
Except that the `dvh` tag adjusts automatically so it changes the layout of all my sections very abruptly and it's really not beautiful :( 

-(I don't know if I'm clear enough).

Comment: @Kylian Hmm, this could be a bit of a difficult. In ios Instagram (well, any browser) should use the same rendering as safari; does the same happen in safari? I see you already updated your test page to use the javascript approach; is that working for you? I don't have an actual iphone to verify. I have one other suggestion to give; would using scroll snaps help with the resizing content? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap/Basic_concepts

Comment: Thank you for your answer, indeed I tried an approach in JS and it works at first sight I have no more "bug" of layout when I scroll on browsers with a nav bar.
I just looked at the Scroll Snap, I don't think it would avoid my layout problem but on the other hand it's very cool, I didn't know, I note, I like a lot the style it does :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : I finally switched to a JS approach that works pretty well, and avoids having to systematically resize my sections on some mobile browsers.

Just by getting the mobile screen height and applying it to my sections with the px unit.

```
var screenHeight = screen.height;

document.getElementById('section1').setAttribute("style","height:"+screenHeight+"px");
document.getElementById('section2').setAttribute("style","height:"+screenHeight+"px");
document.getElementById('section3').setAttribute("style","height:"+screenHeight+"px");
```